# tem como diminuir os ifs? no python

Tags: python-3.x, funções, if

Estou começando na programação e gostaria de saber se tem como eu diminuir o usos de ifs

"""

## Classificação de uma pessoa pela sua altura e peso

```
alt = float(input("Digite a sua altura"))

p = float(input('Digite seu peso'))


if alt < 1.20 and p <= 60:
    print(f'Classificação A')
elif alt < 1.20 and 60 < p < 90:
    print(f'Classificação D')

elif alt < 1.20 and p > 90:
    print(f'Classificação G')

elif 1.20 < alt < 1.70 and p <= 60:
    print(f'Classificação B')

elif 1.20 < alt < 1.70 and 60 < p < 90:
    print(f'Classificação E')

elif 1.20 < alt < 1.70 and p > 90:
    print(f'Classificação H')

elif alt > 1.70 and p <= 60:
    print('Classificação C')

elif alt > 1.70 and 60 < p < 90:
    print('Classificação F')

elif alt > 1.70 and p > 90:
    print('Classificação I')
```

Comment: Para esse código, não vejo motivo em diminuir os `ifs`, mas você pode substituir por `switch` ou por uma `função (def)`

Comment: Eu ainda não intendo a dificuldade de *copiar* e *colar* o código... a pessoa faz o mais difícil e o que menos ajuda...

Comment: não vai diminuir mas usa logica para otimizar, olhe atentamente e vera que vc valida 3 vezes (alt < 1.20), 3 vezes  (1.20 < alt < 1.70) e 3 vezes (alt > 1.70), o ideal é diminuir para apenas uma validação

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Tente testar os extremos primeiro: Por exemplo, todas as alturas menor do 1.20, e dentro disso, todos os pesos. E igualmente para os pesos: menores do que 60, ou maiores do que 90.

Exemplo:

```py
alt = float(input("Digite a sua altura"))

p = float(input('Digite seu peso'))


if alt < 1.20:
  if p <= 60:
    print(f'Classificação A')
  elif p >= 90:
    print('Classificação G')
  else:
    print(f'Classificação D')
elif alt > 1.70:
  if p <= 60: 
    print('Classifição C')
  elif p > 90:
    print('Classificação I')
  else: 
    print('Classificação F')
else: 
  if p <= 60:
    print('Classificação B')
  elif p > 90:
    print('Classificação H')
  else: 
    print('Classificação E')
```